# How to build python package and migrate to alpine

Tags: python, docker, alpine-linux

Is there a way to write a dockerfile firstly build a local python package using docker container, and then migrate this building package file to alpine container?

Comment: If i understood your requirement correctly, You can use alpne version of python docker image.

Comment: The python-alpine is about 100mb size so bigger than the alpine (about 20mb size).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to do.

You can leverage the multi stage building of docker:

```
# temp stage
FROM python:3.9-alpine as builder

WORKDIR /app

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gcc

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip wheel --no-cache-dir --no-deps --wheel-dir /app/wheels -r requirements.txt


# final stage
FROM python:3.9-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=builder /app/wheels /wheels
COPY --from=builder /app/requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --no-cache /wheels/*
```

Source: https://testdriven.io/blog/docker-best-practices/#use-multi-stage-builds

Comment: (You may need to use an Alpine-based image for the first stage too, particularly if you wind up installing a Python package that uses C extensions.)